# Replacing specific column of an array with another array: Error Reason

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to solve a set of linear equations which are solved recursively. At each time step, my solution is `gamma` having the shape of `(3,1)`. This system is iteratively solved 20 times to get to the final value of `gamma`.

I am trying to store the values of `gamma` in each time in another array so that I can access the values of `gamma` at each step after the code run is complete. When I try storing the `gamma` value after each step into gamma_solution, it gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Input code:

```
gamma_solution = np.zeros((3,#_of_steps))

for i in range(#_of_steps):
    <code to solve a system of equations to give gamma as result>
    gamma_solution[:,i].reshape((3,1)) = gamma
```

Output:

```
Error
```

Expectation: At each step i, store the value of gamma obtained in the step in the ith column​ of gamma_solution

Comment: You can do `gamma_solution[:,i] = gamma` (provided `gamma` is a 3 element array.  What it's complaining about is `....reshape() = gamma`, where `reshape()` is the function call.  `gamma_solution[].reshape(...)` is used to produce a new array (a `view`).  You can't combine that with the `=` assignment.   If you need to match shapes across the `=`, do it on the RHS, `solution[:,i] = gamma.reshape(...)`.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thank you for your comment. It does make sense. I did not see it that clearly as I am still a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  `gamma_solution` shape is 3xN,  `gamma_solution[:, j] shape is (3,), so  you need to transpose`gamma`(that has shape (3, 1)) to store it in j-th column of`gamma_solution`. See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
gamma_solution = np.zeros((3, N))
gamma = np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis]
for j in range(N):  # main loop where gamma values are computed
    gamma_solution[:, j] = gamma.T
```

Comment: This worked. I was so stupid I missed it. Thanks a ton!